# Excluir arquivo escolhido de uma lista e subtrair do valor total - Ionic

Tags: array, ionic, ionic3, ionic2, arraylist

Estou desenvolvendo um app com o ionic 3 e o Firebase. Estou enfrentando problemas, pois, ele não está diminuindo o valor do produto(escolhido) do total. Subtrai sempre o ultimo valor informado. Segue o código :

```
deleteProduto(element) {
 if(this.vetCarrinho.length > 1){
   this.vetCarrinho.splice(this.vetCarrinho.indexOf(element), 1); 
   this.acum = (this.acum - this.valTot); 
   this.pedido.total = element;
```

função de salvar :

```
irParaCarrinho(element) {  
element = this.pedido.carrinho;    

this.vetCarrinho.push(element);  
console.log(this.vetCarrinho);
this.pedido.carrinho = this.vetCarrinho;

for (let i = 0; i < this.vetCarrinho.length; i++) {
    this.acumulador = this.valTot;       
  }    
  this.acum += this.acumulador;
  this.pedido.total = this.acum;
  this.desabilitar = true;
```

Comment: Qual variável está retornando valor errado? É a `this.acum`? O que é o `this.valTot`? Não deveria ser o valor do elemento? Algo como `element.valor`.

Comment: Os produtos tem o valor total (this.valTot) que seria, o preço de venda x quantidade. Na lista de produtos, quando tento excluir um produto, ele diminui sempre do total, o this.valTot, do ultimo elemento.

Comment: Entendo que o melhor seria verificar o valor total do elemento dentro da função `deleteProduto(element)`, que é onde você informa qual é o elemento que será excluído. A variável `element` armazena o valor total ou o preço de venda e quantidade do produto?

Comment: Estou armazenando os produtos informados, num vetor, mas não estou informando o seu preço. Analisei friamente e vi que o erro é esse. Aí vem outra questão: Como faço pra armazenar o produto e seu preço no vetor, e depois subtrair o valor do elemento escolhido ?

Comment: Se você postar o restante do código fica mais fácil para entender seu problema. Por exemplo, de onde vem o `element`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta